# VUGen (Loadrunner) script is not recodring for https protocal web application

Tags: web-applications, https, performance-testing, recording, loadrunner

When i tried to record https:// web application in VUGen (loadrunner 11) i am unable to record and got an error message "Internet Explorer cannot diplay the webpage" means not connecting to the server. Application working fine when manually open in browser, issue is only while recording.

FYI..
Product Name: HP LoadRunner Software 11.04 
Lr Protocal : Web(HTTP/HTML)
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and 64bit
Anti-virus :Symantic end point protection is running on this machine
IE Version : 8.0
application protocal :https

Can someone please help me? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

- Check with the URL whether it is correct or not.
- At same time try following the below process

click on record button-->record options-->click on mapping and filtering in networks-->In port mapping set capture level to "WinInet level data if u use IE" and "Socket level data for Mozilla"

Try with above process it might resolve your problem.
[Click on this to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZjVT.png)

Answer (score 0):

See release notes regarding recording a 64 bit application with 32 bit vugen.

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can find place to the Correct URL on the marked place]

- Make sure that the URL is spelled correctly.
- Ensure that the Internet Connection is working.
- If you still have the problem, send me the image attachment.
  this make understanding the problem easily

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11723890)

Comment: i have attached an image.. click on the link to view the image., where u may easily understand...